# Listing large file's set via REST /drive/v3/files: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: google-drive-api

We always get an error next to ~50k items are fetched via Drive API call(during some page requesting):

```
/drive/v3/files?alt=json&fields=nextPageToken,files(id,name,...)&orderBy=createdTime&pageSize=300&pageToken=~!!~AI9FV7S..._fUrCGbeiAQZpIQmwItY=&q=+trashed=false&quotaUser=yoav@k...n.comHTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
User-Agent: google-api-go-client/0.5

Response: HTTP/2.0 500 Internal Server Error
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0

Expires: Thu, 19 Dec 2019 12:19:19 GMT
Server: GSE
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
{ "error": {  "code": 500,  "message": null }}
```

Simplified golang code which produces the request:

```
func example(ds *drive.Service, currentUserID string) error {
    request := ds.Files.List()
    list, err := request.Do(googleapi.QuotaUser(currentUserID))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    process(list)
    for {
        nextPageToken := list.NextPageToken
        if nextPageToken == "" {
            break
        }
        request = request.PageToken(nextPageToken)
        list, err = request.Do(googleapi.QuotaUser(currentUserID))
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        process(list)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Could you please explain why the request crashes server? and how we can fix it?

Thanks in advance, Konstantin

Comment: How many requests are you doing? The maximum pageSize is 1000 so how are you getting 50k files in an API call?

Comment: It's single request with default page size. Error appears during some page requesting.

Comment: Are you doing this with a code? If so, please provide it.

Comment: Please edit the question adding the formatted code.